# What (ML) algorithms take an image as input and optimal action as output?

Tags: neural-network, image-recognition, reference-request, genetic-algorithms

I have a given 2d image describing a top down view of a grid (think e.g. a labirynth.)
I want an algorithm to take it as an input and return a single action to be performed in the setting of this grid.
Then, this algorithm would be producing and applying the actions it came up with until some particular state $S$ is reached in this grid.
I would like this algorithm to produce the optimal (shortest) sequence of actions necessary to achieve $S$.

I was thinking of using the NEAT algorithm since evaluations would be quick to calculate (length of the sequence of actions.)

Am I describing a problem that has been solved - in a perhaps different shape or form - many times in the past? What algorithm should I use?
Would NEAT perform well in high dimensional input?

Because I might use this problem as a side project, I'd rather not go into big details. Googling for research papers brought me nothing and so I would be thankful for any general guidance.

Comment: How many images do you have? Are they already labeled? How many actions do you want? You won't receive accurate answers with this question.